# Intellij 2017.2 does not scale

Tags: intellij-idea, hidpi

After updating to 2017.2 Intellij IDEA does not scale properly on Dell Ultrasharp U2415b. The icons are very big and the workspace is very small.

I have checked, that Intellij changed something with HiDPI support.

Anyone facing the same problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a workaround on https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/intellij-idea-2017-2-is-here-smart-sleek-and-snappy/:

> The fact is that “the better HiDPI support” is currently limited to
>   integral scale displays only, which is not your case. IDEA should have
>   auto-switched to the previous HiDPI mode on start, but it
>   unfortunately didn’t work for you. The problem should be fixed in the
>   upcoming update: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173258
>
> Until it’s fixed, please reset the HiDPI mode manually by providing
>   the VM option (Help > Edit Custom VM Options):
>
> `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false`
>
> Then restart. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Still an issue in 2018.1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185238#u=1516378592982

Comment: Just had to add this in PyCharm 2019.1, using Ubuntu 18.04 on a DELL laptop with an external screen and joint displays

Comment: Still an issue in 2020.1

Comment: Still an issue in 2021.1.1.RC

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading ubuntu and android studio, i hade to

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2

and

> export GDK_DPI_SCALE=1